# how to get the value of XML in java

Tags: java, xml

How to parse this type of XML in java

**example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<isomsg direction="incoming">
   <id id="2" value="929501003300038807"/>
   <id id="3" value="0301100"/>
   <id id="4" value="000000000000"/>
</isomsg>
```

Now,i want to get the value `929501003300038807,0301100,000000000000`

Comment: Helpful link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Your xml is invalid `id="2` is not a valid attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example using jaxb

Assuming you have the following XML, please note I corrected the

```
 <id="2" value="929501003300038807"/> to 

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <isomsg direction="incoming">
       <id id="2" value="929501003300038807"/>
       <id id="3" value="0301100"/>
       <id id="4" value="000000000000"/>
  </isomsg>
```

**Isomsg class for the isomsg element**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "isomsg")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Isomsg
{

  @XmlElement(name = "id")
  private List<XMLObject> idList = null;

  public List<XMLObject> getIdList()
  {
    return idList;
  }

  public void setIdList(List<XMLObject> idList)
  {
    this.idList = idList;
  }
}
```

**XMLObject class for the id element**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "id")
public class XMLObject
{
  int id;
  String value;

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public void setId(int id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public void setValue(String value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

**XMLRunner to test your class**

```
   public class XMLRunner
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    doFromFile("d:\\myxml.xml");
    doFromString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n" +
            "    <isomsg direction=\"incoming\">\n" +
            "        <id id=\"2\" value=\"929501003300038807\"/>\n" +
            "        <id id=\"3\" value=\"0301100\"/>\n" +
            "        <id id=\"4\" value=\"000000000000\"/>\n" +
            "   </isomsg>    ");
  }

  public static void doFromFile(String filename)
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("About to unmarshal from file : " + filename);
      File file = new File(filename);
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Isomsg.class);

      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      Isomsg isomsg = (Isomsg) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
      System.out.println("You have " + isomsg.getIdList().size() + " items");

      for (XMLObject xmlObject : isomsg.getIdList())
      {
        System.out.println(xmlObject.getValue());
      }
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void doFromString(String xmlString)
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("About to unmarshal from string  : " + xmlString);
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Isomsg.class);

      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

      StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
      Isomsg isomsg = (Isomsg) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
      System.out.println("You have " + isomsg.getIdList().size() + " items");

      for (XMLObject xmlObject : isomsg.getIdList())
      {
        System.out.println(xmlObject.getValue());
      }
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: actually i want to parse this xml from String not file, how could i solve this.

Comment: @KawshikRoy , I have edited my post , method doFromString() will unmarshal from a String

Comment: Thanks  @ Kenneth Clark:)